# Strange padding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Please look [at this page](http://vefaestetik.az/?debug)

What I want to achieve is

[image]

and

[image]

Using following jQ function to dynamically resize div height based on document height

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.sideBg').css({ 'height': ($(document).height())});
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Blender can't you see that, pattern padded from top and bottom?

Comment: So... you want there to be no padding between the pattern and the top and bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better if you just used the `background` on the `body`? This way, you don't even need the additional elements or JavaScript.

```
body {
  background: url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png),
              url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png) 100% 0, 
              black radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #45484D 0%,black 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Don't forget to use `background: black url(/design/img/bg/000.png);` for the footer.

And don't forget that you should also have the prefixed versions

```
background: url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png),
                  url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png) 100% 0, 
                  black -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #45484D 0%,black 100%);
background: url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png),
                  url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png) 100% 0, 
                  black -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #45484D 0%,black 100%);
background: url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png),
                  url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png) 100% 0, 
                  black -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #45484D 0%,black 100%);
```

***before*** the unprefixed one in the styles for the body.

Works for me if I make these changes via Developer Tools

[image: screenshot]

**About compatibility**: multiple backgrounds have better support than gradients ([**multiple backgrounds are supported by IE9**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds), while [**CSS gradients are not**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)). Actually, this won't work in IE 9 precisely because of the gradient. However, you can make it work in IE9 *without the gradient* by adding ***before*** all the prefixed versions a multiple background fallback (without the gradient).

```
background: url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png),
            black url(http://vefaestetik.az/design/img/bg/side_bg.png) 100% 0;
```

Comment: is that cross browser compatible ?

Comment: Because you need to use radial gradient with prefixes

Comment: Is that cross browser compatible?

Comment: `background-repeat: repeat-y;` after all the background declarations. And see my answer with compatibility update.

Comment: See the last part of my answer, after the image.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the `margin-top` that is on your `.wrapper <div>` for the top to be fixed:

```
.wrapper {
    background: url("/design/img/wrapper-bg.png") no-repeat center top;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*margin-top: 20px; remove this */
    padding-top: 120px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1020px;
}
```

Then for the bottom part i would suggest to get the height of the `.wrapper <div>`:

```
$(function() {
  var wrapperHeight = $('.wrapper').height();
  $('.sideBg').css('height': +wrapperHeight+'px');
});
```

Comment: but wrapper must be padded from top

Comment: then you need to negative the margin-top from the .sideBg {margin-top: -20px;}

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing unnecessary `padding` always use a reset.css file.

Copy the code from here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/